# JBoss 5.1.0 GA with Apache Load Balancer

Tags: apache-2.2, jboss, mod-jk

I've followed the tutorial here: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/UsingModjk12WithJBoss

All my files as configured as it says there but then I try to access http://localhost/jmx-console I get

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /jmx-console.

Reason: DNS lookup failure for: host1
```

If I call http://localhost/admin/ the browser seems to be loading forever.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I think you're going to need to post some more info before anyone can provide an answer. Try including the relevant information from your apache and modjk configuration files. Can you get to /jmx-console when you access your jboss instance directly (bypassing apache)?

Comment: Here is my httpd.conf :
http://pastebin.com/3EDqhm0V and 
httpf.conf : http://pastebin.com/Cm7DKcdm
mod-jk : http://pastebin.com/3Wug1Z7t , 
uriworkermap.properties : http://pastebin.com/hDiSyhSq and 
workers.properties : http://pastebin.com/RxPeA7yb .

With these configured I can acces http://localhost/myapp-1 and http://localhost/myapp-2 but not http://localhost/jmx-console/ .

Thank you.

Comment: Try commenting out lines 488+ in your httpd.conf. It looks like you may have been trying to use mod_proxy at some point and left that in? Those lines are causing it try to proxy requests for /jmx-console to a server called "host1" which does not seem to exist in your environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of recording an answer: Comment out the unused mod_proxy directives in the httpd.conf file.

Comment: With the same config files, I start a second JBoss instance on another PC, and when I call http://192.168.224.5:80/autoid/ I get time-outs. The only modification between the two JBoss's is jvmRoute="node2" in server.xml in the second computer. Is that correct ?

Comment: I've also added in mod-jk.conf Allow from 192.168.224.160 (the IP of my second computer) under the <Location /jkstatus> tag but to no use.

Comment: Ignore the above post. Firewall issues.